# How to find the job which is printing credentials on console logs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a security project where I need to Prevent output of sensitive data.We have more than 100 jobs running in Jenkins machine and its very difficult to check the jobs one by one .Is there any way to check the jobs which are printing credential in console output?Can someone suggest.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Subhadeep mentioned - mask passwords plugin is a right tool to mask credentials in jobs' output. It will help you in the future.

If you want to check which jobs with which build numbers showed credentials in plain text - it's better to use grep or analogues.

For example:

```
grep -e psw -o -r /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking into jenkins console output for password/credentials, you can look to implement jenkins mask password plugin and hide your password printing in plain text in console output.
There are some tools available which you can use to scan jenkins console log.
One of the tool is Veracode Jenkins Plugin.
Till you can find out any way, you can limit the access who can see the console.
You may use matrix base security for this and only admin people can see console log.

Thanks,
Subhadeep

Comment: Thanks for your response,But in current scenario I dont know which all jobs showing password in console log to mask the password .And also there are some use case in which console log is necessary for user to verify .So I cant block it.